# Parsing some xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have some prices written in XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
    <asks type="array">
        <ask type="array">
            <ask type="decimal">0.00451997</ask>
            <ask type="decimal">22.1239917</ask>
        </ask>
        <ask type="array">
            <ask type="decimal">0.00451998</ask>
            <ask type="decimal">2.21239917</ask>
        </ask>
        <ask type="array">
            <ask type="decimal">0.00451999</ask>
            <ask type="decimal">5.0</ask>
        </ask>
        <ask type="array">
            <ask type="decimal">0.00452</ask>
            <ask type="decimal">1.8</ask>
        </ask>
    </asks>
    <bids type="array">
        <bid type="array">
            <bid type="decimal">0.00431</bid>
            <bid type="decimal">76.15234365</bid>
        </bid>
        <bid type="array">
            <bid type="decimal">0.0042</bid>
            <bid type="decimal">100.0</bid>
        </bid>
        <bid type="array">
            <bid type="decimal">0.00411</bid>
            <bid type="decimal">99.9</bid>
        </bid>

    </bids>
    <status type="integer">0</status>
    <statustext>0</statustext>
</hash>
```

I want to store these in a table in a database. But the  tag contains various numbers of  tags. How do I iterate over these in the nicest possible way?

Comment: Al your `<ask>` and `<bid>` tags contain 2 elements, is that the rule?

Comment: The `nicest possible way` sounds like an opinion based question. What are your requirements? Which .NET framework? Which database (Oracle, SQL Server, mySQL)? How does your database design look like?

Comment: There's like thousand questions on XML parsing. Have you bothered yourself with searching?

Comment: You could just store the XML as a blob in one varchar column in the database. What requirements do you have that mean you want to store the XML in a different format. Do you already have a DB schema for this data?

Answer (score 0):

You must somehow know the name of the tags, then create a list of possible tags and extract prices, like this:

```
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Your xml document path"); // or XDocument.Parse("Xml string");
    List<string> tags = new List<string>() { "ask", "bid" }; // Build list of tags here
    List<decimal> prices = new List<decimal>();
    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        prices.AddRange(xDoc.Descendants(tag).Where(xe => xe.Attribute("type").Value == "decimal").Select(xe => decimal.Parse(xe.Value)));
    }
```

if you don't know the tag names at all but the price tag element always contains `type="decimal"` attribute you can use this instead:

```
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Your xml document path");
    List<decimal> prices = new List<decimal>();
    prices.AddRange(xDoc.Descendants().Where(xe => xe.Attribute("type") != null && xe.Attribute("type").Value == "decimal").Select(xe => decimal.Parse(xe.Value)));
```

Note that using `Descendants` is not considered the most optimized way, but it's easy to use if your xml document is not too large.